# Geo Pandas - Using 1 dataframe to limit another

Tags: python, geopandas

I have 2 dataframes. For this, lets call it df1 and df2.

df1 only has a single row, and is identified by a code called "SA4_CODE21".
df2 has 400 rows, and contains records for each example that exists in a country, but in reality, only 47 will match if you were using an INNER JOIN similar to SQL.

What is the correct syntax, using a geopandas object to limit df2 specifically to WHERE = SA4_CODE21, so to return the correct records?

Regards

Tried various merge, concat and other elements but have been unable to resolve.

Comment: Did you tried spatial join in geo pandas. 
Refer to this documentation - https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to Rome, but e.g. pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) should do the trick...

The examples below use standard DataFrames for simplicity, but GeoDataFrames work the same way.

Something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"SA4_CODE21": ["foo"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"SA4_CODE21": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

result = df2.merge(df1, on="SA4_CODE21", how="inner")
print(result)
```

Result:

```
  SA4_CODE21  c
0        foo  1
1        foo  3
```

You could also use pandas [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join), like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"SA4_CODE21": ["foo"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"SA4_CODE21": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"], "c": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

result = df2.join(df1.set_index("SA4_CODE21"), on="SA4_CODE21", how="inner")
print(result)
```

Result:

```
  SA4_CODE21  c
0        foo  1
2        foo  3
```